# Numba.vectorize for CUDA: What is the correct signature to return arrays?

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I have a function of the following structure,

```
@numba.jit(nopython = True)
def foo(X,N):
    '''
    :param X: 1D numpy array
    :param N: Integer
    :rtype: 2D numpy array of shape len(X) x N
    '''
    out = np.ones((len(X),N))
    out[:,0]  = X 
    for i in range(1,N):
        out[:,i] = X**i+out[:,i-1] 
    return out
```

which I am now trying to run on my GPU.
What I tried so far is to write the function in a non-vectorized form (i.e. treat each entry of X separately), and pass the return array as an input:

```
def foo_cuda(x,N,out):
    '''
    :param x: Scalar
    :param N: Integer
    :rtype: 1D numpy array of length N
    '''
    out[0] = x
    for i in range(1,N):
        out[i] = x**i+out[i-1]
```

However, I don't know what decorator to use for that function. If I use

1. `@numba.vectorize([(float64,int64,float64[:])],target = 'cuda')`  I get `TypeError: Buffer dtype cannot be buffer`
2. `@numba.guvectorize([(float64,int64,float64[:])],'(),()->(n)',target = 'cuda')` I get `NameError: undefined output symbols: n`

What is the correct decorator to use for my purpose?

I would like to be able to call `foo_cuda` in roughly the same way as `foo` at the end, i.e. pass a 1D array `X`, an integer `N` and a 2D array `out` that gets filled with the results.

**UPDATE**

The `numpy.vectorize` version of my function would be

```
def foo_np(x,N):
    '''
    :param x: Scalar
    :param N: Integer
    :rtype: 1D numpy array of length N
    '''
    out = np.zeros(N)
    out[0] = x
    for i in range(1,N):
        out[i] = x**i+out[i-1]
    return out
foo_ve = np.vectorize(foo_np,signature='(),()->(n)')
```

However, I cannot create an output array (`out = np.zeros(N)`) in numba (`cuda.local.array(N,dtype=float64)` fails as well), which precludes me from using `@numba.vectorize('void(float64,int64)',target='cuda')`. I tried to fix this by passing an the output array to the function and adding this to the signature (see attempt 1. above), but I got an error.

**UPDATE 2**

The actual function is as follows:

```
@numba.jit(nopython = True)
def foo(X,N):
    '''
    :param X: 1D numpy array
    :param N: Integer >= 2
    :rtype: 2D numpy array of shape len(X) x N
    '''
    out = np.ones((X.shape[0],N))
    out[:,1] = X
    for i in range(2,N):
        out[:,i] = X*out[:,i-1] - (i-1)*out[:,i-2] 
    c = 1
    for i in range(2,N):#Note that this loop cannot be combined with the one above!
        c *= i
        out[:,i] /= math.sqrt(c)
    return out
```

Comment: What is your "purpose"? `vectorize`, `guvectorize`, and `jit` are three very different things and it isn't at all obvious which one of these you actually are trying to write (and saying "run on my GPU") is completely unhelpful. They all can run on the GPU in one form or another). Read http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html

Comment: @talonmies All I know is that I want to accelerate the code. How to achieve that best, I don't know. If all options were working, I could try it out, but I can't get any working. From my understanding, `vectorize` adds another layer where numba takes care of the vectorization by itself, so I don't have to write loops over `X`. The difference between `vectorize` and `guvectorize` I don't know, except that `guvectorize` seems to be more flexible (believe me, the description in your link, which I already had seen, is not very helpful for beginners. I couldn't find a more complete documentation)

Comment: @talonmies Since it probably matters, `len(X)` is normally much larger than `N`

Comment: Your understanding of what vectorize does is incorrect. All of these concepts are more or less identical to those in plain numpy. Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379301/using-numpy-vectorize-on-functions-that-return-vectors . Otherwise there is no answer to your question, I'm afraid. You seems to be trying to ask "What decorator will deliver my free lunch". As with all things in life, there is no free lunch.

Comment: @talonmies I don't think my understanding is as incorrect as you think. Maybe I just expressed myself imprecisely. I do know how numpy's vectorize works, and I do get it working (see update, and my problems with transferring this to CUDA). Again, I am aware that there are a lot of different ways to run stuff on the GPU, but I just have no ideas where to start, since I can't get anything to work. I don't see how I am asking for a free lunch. I believe the functionality that I need is clear; the only reason I don't specify what implementation I have in mind is that I don't know the options

Comment: From the documentation you claim to have read: "Using vectorize(), you write your function as operating over input scalars, rather than arrays". If you want to use `@vectorize`, you are writing functions which will take scalar inputs and produce a scalar output. That gets extrapolated over a set of arrays. Your code doesn't appear to fit that paradigm and why I doubt you understand how this actualy works

Comment: @talonmies, but as my update shows, numpy's `vectorize` also is able to work on functions that take scalars and return arrays. Are you saying that that's not possible with numba's `vectorize`?

Comment: @talonmies as for the documentation that I actually did read. I know that it says that there, but since it worked in numpy I gave it a shot. Also, that is where I saw guvectorize, which I understood is a bit more flexible, which I then also gave a shot.

Comment: @talonmies Could you at least tell me whether your main point is that I'm trying to do something that is much more complicated than I believe, that I'm being too lazy/stupid to do a simple thing myself, or that you don't have enough information to actually help me?

Comment: My point is that what you are trying to do, in its current form, is likely impossible. Your question is what Numba decorator you should use, and the answer is that there isn't one. Numba adds several restrictions on what can be done compared to vectorization in numpy and your code violates those

Comment: @talonmies So if you were in my situation you would write the CUDA code directly and not use Numba?

Comment: No, I would use Numba. But I would write a kernel by hand in Python, not try and find some compiler assisted magic (aka the free lunch) to do it for me

Comment: @talonmies Okay, since the section on 'Writing CUDA kernels' in the numba documentation http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/kernels.html isn't very extensive and links to the CUDA C Programming Guide I guess that is beyond my capabilities then

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the presented code expects to do a prefix sum on `x**i` for `i`<`N`.  If you do a google search on "numba cuda prefix sum", I think you'll find some info that seems relevant (to me, anyway).  I wouldn't really call it an obviously solved problem (e.g. straightforward or library implementation).  As @talonmies said, for many basic operations (including prefix sum) it should be possible to write a numba CUDA python kernel by hand to duplicate how you might do it in CUDA C, and some of the links I saw suggest basically that.

Comment: Although it's not a prefix sum, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087668/why-cant-i-get-the-right-sum-of-1d-array-with-numba-cuda-python) of what I believe @talonmies is referring to by "write a kernel by hand".

Comment: numba cuda vectorize and guvectorize are basically expecting to do elementwise operations, with no interdependencies between computed results.  prefix sum doesn't really fit that template.  Although guvectorize generalizes this a bit, it still doesn't provide a mechanism to exchange intermediate computed results between threads, which is useful for things like parallel reduction and prefix-sum.  This sort of cooperative thread work can be set up using numba cuda python (see previous linked example for parallel reduction) and I believe it could be used to create a prefix sum.

Comment: actually, going back to the original code on `X` instead of `x`,  if you don't parallelize the prefix-sum portion, but simply parallelize over `len(X)`,  then you may be able to follow a method pretty similar to what is [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/numbapro-examples/blob/master/guvectorize/sumrows.py).  If `len(X)` is small, this will probably still be uninteresting, performance-wise.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for your replies. The actual code is more complicated than the above (for each x, it computes the first N terms of a sequence determined by some recurrence formula that involves x). There are absolutely no interdependencies between computed results for different `x`, which is exactly why I assumed GPU, and more particularly `(gu)vectorize`, should be easy and efficient to do. If I still follow your suggestion and don't parallelize over the loop, wouldn't most of the time be spent copying arrays to and from the GPU?

Comment: I can only work off of what I see here.  Yes, I can see that there are no interdependencies for computed results for different `x`, which is why I suggested the method in my last comment.  Regarding your question, we may be saying the same thing - it just took me a while to grasp what you were asking. You actually don't want to parallelize the for-loop you have shown.  That would be a possibly sensible approach if `len(X)` is large.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I added the actual code I am interested in. As to whether we mean the same thing: I mean that the for loop over `range(N)` should probably be performed on the GPU; I believe having the loop on the CPU and the contents of the loop on the GPU would be inefficient. Also, `len(X)` is indeed larger than `N` (`len(X)~1e6` and `N~10` are common). I don't how to follow the example in the link you provided in your second to last comment, however, since it concerns a function that returns scalars

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dug into this a bit, so I'll share what I have.  Whether or not it is a complete answer I'm not sure, but it may address some of your questions.

Probably the best numba-based approach for this is to write your own "custom" CUDA kernel using numba CUDA (jit).  An example of this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087668/why-cant-i-get-the-right-sum-of-1d-array-with-numba-cuda-python) for reduction or [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/examples.html#matrix-multiplication) for matrix multiply.  To do this correctly would require learning something about CUDA programming.  This didn't seem to be the direction you wanted to go in however.

As an alternative your question is focusing on using numba vectorization to generate GPU code.  numba [vectorize](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html) decorator is used for functions which operate on scalar input and output, and the vectorization applies them to matrix input/matrix output.

For functions that don't fit this, e.g. those that operate on a vector or a scalar but produce a vector, or those that operate on one or two vectors, and produce a vector or scalar output, numba provides the generalized [guvectorize](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html).

Starting with your simplest example of what you want to do, we could realize this with `guvectorize`:

> What I tried so far is to write the function in a non-vectorized form (i.e. treat each entry of X separately), and pass the return array as an input:

```
def foo_cuda(x,N,out):
    '''
    :param x: Scalar
    :param N: Integer
    :rtype: 1D numpy array of length N
    '''
    out[0] = x
    for i in range(1,N):
        out[i] = x**i+out[i-1]
```

This intent, to take a scalar (per function call) and return a vector (per function call) falls within the capability of `guvectorize` (with some limitations/caveats - see notes at bottom).

Here is a worked example, derived from the sample code [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/numbapro-examples/blob/master/guvectorize/sumrows.py):

```
# cat t2.py
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

import numpy as np

from numba import guvectorize, cuda

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    range = xrange


#    function type:
#        - has void return type
#
#    signature: (n)->(n)
#        - the function takes an array of n-element and output same.

@guvectorize(['void(float32[:], float32[:])'], '(n) ->(n)', target='cuda')
def my_func(inp, out):
        tmp1 = 0.
        tmp = inp[0]
        for i in range(out.shape[0]):
            tmp1 += tmp
            out[i] = tmp1
            tmp *= inp[0]

# set up input data
rows = 1280000 # shape[0]
cols = 4   # shape[1]
inp = np.zeros(rows*cols, dtype=np.float32).reshape(rows, cols)
for i in range(inp.shape[0]):
    inp[i,0] = (i%4)+1
# invoke on CUDA with manually managed memory

dev_inp = cuda.to_device(inp)             # alloc and copy input data

my_func(dev_inp, dev_inp)             # invoke the gufunc

dev_inp.copy_to_host(inp)                 # retrieve the result

# print out
print('result'.center(80, '-'))
print(inp)

# nvprof --print-gpu-trace python t2.py
==4773== NVPROF is profiling process 4773, command: python t2.py
-------------------------------------result-------------------------------------
[[  1.   2.   3.   4.]
 [  2.   6.  14.  30.]
 [  3.  12.  39. 120.]
 ...
 [  2.   6.  14.  30.]
 [  3.  12.  39. 120.]
 [  4.  20.  84. 340.]]
==4773== Profiling application: python t2.py
==4773== Profiling result:
   Start  Duration            Grid Size      Block Size     Regs*    SSMem*    DSMem*      Size  Throughput  SrcMemType  DstMemType           Device   Context    Stream  Name
994.08ms  5.5731ms                    -               -         -         -         -  19.531MB  3.4224GB/s    Pageable      Device  Tesla P100-PCIE         1         7  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
1.00083s  159.20us          (20000 1 1)        (64 1 1)        22        0B        0B         -           -           -           -  Tesla P100-PCIE         1         7  cudapy::__main__::__gufunc_my_func$242(Array<float, int=2, A, mutable, aligned>, Array<float, int=2, A, mutable, aligned>) [48]
1.00100s  4.8017ms                    -               -         -         -         -  19.531MB  3.9722GB/s      Device    Pageable  Tesla P100-PCIE         1         7  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]

Regs: Number of registers used per CUDA thread. This number includes registers used internally by the CUDA driver and/or tools and can be more than what the compiler shows.
SSMem: Static shared memory allocated per CUDA block.
DSMem: Dynamic shared memory allocated per CUDA block.
SrcMemType: The type of source memory accessed by memory operation/copy
DstMemType: The type of destination memory accessed by memory operation/copy

# nvprof --metrics gst_efficiency python t2.py
==4787== NVPROF is profiling process 4787, command: python t2.py
==4787== Some kernel(s) will be replayed on device 0 in order to collect all events/metrics.
Replaying kernel "cudapy::__main__::__gufunc_my_func$242(Array<float, int=2, A, mutable, aligned>, Array<float, int=2, A, mutable, aligned>)" (done)
-------------------------------------result-------------------------------------
[[  1.   2.   3.   4.]
 [  2.   6.  14.  30.]
 [  3.  12.  39. 120.]
 ...
 [  2.   6.  14.  30.]
 [  3.  12.  39. 120.]
 [  4.  20.  84. 340.]]
==4787== Profiling application: python t2.py
==4787== Profiling result:
==4787== Metric result:
Invocations                               Metric Name                        Metric Description         Min         Max         Avg
Device "Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (0)"
    Kernel: cudapy::__main__::__gufunc_my_func$242(Array<float, int=2, A, mutable, aligned>, Array<float, int=2, A, mutable, aligned>)
          1                            gst_efficiency            Global Memory Store Efficiency      25.00%      25.00%      25.00%
#
```

To respond to your specific question in the context of `guvectorize`:

> What is the correct decorator to use for my purpose?

The function type specification looks like this:

```
['<return-type>(<parameter 0 type>, <parameter 1 type>, ...)']
```

For `guvectorize`, the return type should always be `void`.  The types of the parameters should match the types you intend the function to be used with.  With `guvectorize` we think about types as a "slice" of the actual input and output data types we will pass, the "slice" being what an individual function call will operate on.  The vectorization then applies individual function calls to each "slice" of the input/output data, to cover the entire size of the input/output data set.   For my example, then, I am proposing to pass an input vector (`float32[:]`) and an output vector (`float32[:]`).

The function signature shows the dimensions of the input, followed by the dimensions of the output:

```
(x)...->(x)
```

Each can be multidimensional (although should still represent only a "slice" of the input/output, for vectorization), and scalar can be represented by `()`.  A wrinkle arises here, since we want the output "slice" to be a vector of results, of some length, say `n`.  numba `guvectorize` does not seem to allow the specification of an output dimension (`n`) that is not part of an already specified input dimension.  So while this function only really needs a scalar input, I have chosen to work around this by passing a vector "slice" for input and output.  In fact this function, the way I have written it, can use the same data for input and output, so there isn't really "overhead" to this workaround, for this particular case.

Some notes about implementation/performance:

1. This "parallelizes" across the first array (`shape[0]`) dimension.  *All of the computations are being performed on the GPU*.  The computations to perform each vector slice of the output are being performed by a single thread on the GPU.  But for a large data set (first dimension) this will expose plenty of parallel work (threads) for the GPU.  The work in the second dimension, i.e. the loop, is operating in the context of each thread.  Attempting to parallelize in the second dimension (creating e.g. a prefix sum) would almost certainly not be possible using `vectorize` or `guvectorize` but should be possible using numba cuda (jit).  We can confirm the parallelization dimension by studying the (first) `nvprof --print-gpu-trace` output in the above worked example, and noting that it constitutes 20000 blocks of 64 threads each, for a total of 1280000 threads, matching our first array dimension.
2. As mentioned already, this implementation is somewhat hacky as I am passing a vector input even though I only need and use a scalar.  This is to work around what seems to be a limitation in numba that you cannot specify a dimension signature like `()->(n)` as far as I can tell.  (Note: after further study, I think the right thing to do here is to define an *input-only* ufunc, passing the input vector/matrix as just a single argument instead of twice, and using just `(n)`  as the dimension signature, rather than `(n)->(n)`.  See [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/jit-compilation.html) ).
3. This implementation is not optimal from a memory access pattern point of view.  This is evident from the (second) `nvprof --metrics gst_efficiency` output.  I think the reason for this is also possibly a limitation in numba design (currently).  When numba is presented an array in this example for distribution/parallelization via `guvectorize`, it slices the array into rows, and passes each row to a function call to process.  For this particular example, a much more efficient implementation would be to transpose our array storage system, and have the array sliced into columns, and let each function call work on a column. The reason for this has to do with GPU behavior and design, which I won't review here.  However the metric shows that we're only achieving 25% efficiency with this row-per-thread access pattern.  It would be easy to achieve 100% efficiency with transposed data and a column-per-thread approach, but I don't know how to achieve this with numba `guvectorize`.  The only option I know of to resolve the inefficient access would be to revert to writing a numba CUDA kernel (i.e. CUDA jit).  (Another alternative I tried to investigate was to see if we could instruct the ufunc to take a column-vector in its signature, e.g. something like `void(float32[[:]],float32[[:]])`, hoping that numba would slice things by columns, but had no luck with that.)

Using the previous example as a model, we can create something similar that solves your "actual function" in Update 2, using `guvectorize`.  I've reduced the array sizes here to 5 (= `len(X)`) by 4 (= `N`):

```
# cat t3.py
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import numpy as np
import numba

from numba import guvectorize, cuda
import math

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    range = xrange

@numba.jit(nopython = True)
def foo(X,N):
    '''
    :param X: 1D numpy array
    :param N: Integer >= 2
    :rtype: 2D numpy array of shape len(X) x N
    '''
    out = np.ones((X.shape[0],N))
    out[:,1] = X
    for i in range(2,N):
        out[:,i] = X*out[:,i-1] - (i-1)*out[:,i-2]
    c = 1
    for i in range(2,N):#Note that this loop cannot be combined with the one above!
        c *= i
        out[:,i] /= math.sqrt(c)
    return out

#    function type:
#        - has void return type
#
#    signature: (n)->(n)
#        - the function takes an array of n-element and output same.

@guvectorize(['void(float32[:], float32[:])'], '(n) ->(n)', target='cuda')
def my_func(inp, out):
        for i in range(2,out.shape[0]):
            out[i] = out[1]*out[i-1] - (i-1)*out[i-2]
        c = 1.
        for i in range(2,out.shape[0]):
            c *= i
            out[i] /= math.sqrt(c)

# set up input data
rows = 5   # shape[0]
cols = 4   # shape[1]
inp = np.ones(rows*cols, dtype=np.float32).reshape(rows, cols)
for i in range(inp.shape[0]):
    inp[i,1] = i
# invoke on CUDA with manually managed memory

dev_inp = cuda.to_device(inp)             # alloc and copy input data

my_func(dev_inp, dev_inp)             # invoke the gufunc

dev_inp.copy_to_host(inp)                 # retrieve the result

# print out
print('gpu result'.center(80, '-'))
print(inp)

rrows = rows
rcols = cols
rin = np.zeros(rrows, dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(rin.shape[0]):
    rin[i] = i
rout = foo(rin, rcols)
print('cpu result'.center(80, '-'))
print(rout)


# python t3.py
-----------------------------------gpu result-----------------------------------
[[ 1.          0.         -0.70710677 -0.        ]
 [ 1.          1.          0.         -0.8164966 ]
 [ 1.          2.          2.1213202   0.8164966 ]
 [ 1.          3.          5.656854    7.3484693 ]
 [ 1.          4.         10.606602   21.22891   ]]
-----------------------------------cpu result-----------------------------------
[[ 1.          0.         -0.70710678 -0.        ]
 [ 1.          1.          0.         -0.81649658]
 [ 1.          2.          2.12132034  0.81649658]
 [ 1.          3.          5.65685425  7.34846923]
 [ 1.          4.         10.60660172 21.2289111 ]]
#
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046102/numba-and-guvectorize-for-cuda-target-code-running-slower-than-expected/52132523#52132523) has additional discussion on the concept of "slices" as they pertain to `vectorize` and `guvectorize`, and walks through a number of examples.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm happy the decorator approach works after all (and not much more complicated than I had thought). My code is now 5 times faster with `len(X)=1e6`, `N=10`. One question: Why do you  use float32 when my question used float64? This is not to criticize you, it's an easy fix, but I wonder if there is a deeper reason behind this (I've seen it elsewhere too) than just accelerating by a factor 2 (I happen to really need the extra precision)

Comment: It was an oversight, however `float32` calculations run faster on most GPUs.  use `float64` if you must, or `float32` if you can, for performance, usually.

Comment: fwiw, column vector format would be format='F'(ortran).  The type notation would be `int32(::1, :)` which means "group data by first dimension / column".

Comment: @Ajax none of that seems to affect how numba divides up the input matrices between workers.  The workers seem to always operate on rows (in memory).  Note that I'm not wondering how to transpose the data.  For example what I'd like to do is create a `guvectorize` ufunc that sums the rows of a matrix in memory (which I know how to do) and another `guvectorize` ufunc the sums the columns of the same matrix in memory (which I don't know how to do).

Comment: Perhaps this library might help you https://github.com/cupy/cupy/blob/master/cupy/manipulation/join.py#L5

Comment: Also, in case you missed it, there is a `T()` on all arrays that performs a transpose operation.  For increasing guvectorize mastery, I'll also share this excellent post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046102/numba-and-guvectorize-for-cuda-target-code-running-slower-than-expected