# Using NumPy array operations with Numba's @guvectorize

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I've been experimenting with Numba lately, and here's something that I still cannot understand:

In a normal Python function with NumPy arrays you can do something like this:

```
# Subtracts two NumPy arrays and returns an array as the result
def sub(a, b):
    res = a - b
    return res
```

But, when you use Numba's `@guvectorize` decorator like so:

```
# Subtracts two NumPy arrays and returns an array as the result
@guvectorize(['void(float32[:], float32[:], float32[:])'],'(n),(n)->(n)')
def subT(a, b, res):
    res = a - b
```

The result is not even correct. Worse still, there are instances where it complains about "Invalid usage of [math operator] with [parameters]"

I am baffled. Even if I try this:

```
# Subtracts two NumPy arrays and returns an array as the result
@guvectorize(['void(float32[:], float32[:], float32[:])'],'(n),(n)->(n)')
def subTt(a, b, res):
    res = np.subtract(a,b)
```

The result is still incorrect. Considering that [this is supposed to be a supported Math operation](http://numba.pydata.org/numbadoc/0.38.0/reference/numpysupported.html), I don't see why it doesn't work.

I know the standard way is like this:

```
# Subtracts two NumPy arrays and returns an array as the result
@guvectorize(['void(float32[:], float32[:], float32[:])'],'(n),(n)->(n)')
def subTtt(a, b, res):
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        res[i] = a[i] - b[i]
```

and this does work as per expected.

But what is wrong with my way?

P/S This is just a trivial example to explain my problem, I don't actually plan to use `@guvectorize` just to subtract arrays :P
P/P/S I suspect it has something to do with how the arrays are copied to gpu memory, but I am not sure...
P/P/P/S [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087668/why-cant-i-get-the-right-sum-of-1d-array-with-numba-cuda-python) looked relevant but the function here operates only on a single thread right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to write this is:

```
@guvectorize(['void(float32[:], float32[:], float32[:])'],'(n),(n)->(n)')
def subT(a, b, res):
    res[:] = a - b
```

The reason what you tried didn't work is a limitation of python syntax not particular to numba.

`name = expr` rebinds the value of name to expr, it can never mutate the original value of name, as you could with, e.g. c++ references.

`name[] = expr` calls (in essence), `name.__setitem__` which can be used to modify name, as numpy arrays do, the empty slice `[:]` refers to the whole array.

Comment: pardon my question, but why does the "normal" Python function work then?

Comment: It works because you are returning `res` where as in a gufunc you need to mutate the input.

Comment: hmm alright, thanks! seems like I still need to learn more Python