# How to use supported numpy and math functions with CUDA in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, numba

According to `numba 0.51.2` [documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/0.51.2/cuda/cudapysupported.html), CUDA Python supports several `math` functions. However, it doesn't work in the following kernel function:

```py
@cuda.jit
def find_angle(angles):
    i, j = cuda.grid(2)
    if i < angles.shape[0] and j < angles.shape[1]:
        angles[i][j] = math.atan2(j, i)
```

The output:

```
numba.core.errors.LoweringError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
No definition for lowering <built-in function atan2>(int64, int64) -> float64
```

Am I using the function incorrectly?

Comment: Well `arctan2` isn't  in the list of supported functions on the page you link. Your text description of support is also not what I find when I look at that page.  I don't see that "most" `math` functions are supported, I see that a list of supported functions is provided.  If you look on the `numba` tag here on SO, you'll find examples of `math` usage, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745701/numba-cuda-does-not-produce-correct-result-with-gpu-reduction-needed/53748514#53748514).

Comment: @RobertCrovella I wrote the question in the middle of debugging both the `math` and `numpy` errors and confused the situation a bit. To clear up the question, I directed the question to supported `math` functions, specifically `math.atan(y, x)`. The link provides the functions supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint to the source of the problem is here:

`No definition for lowering <built-in function atan2>(int64, int64) -> float64`

The arguments returned by `cuda.grid()` (i.e. `i`, `j` which you are passing to `atan2`) are integer values because they are related to indexing.

numba can't find a version of `atan2` that it can use that takes two integer arguments and returns a floating-point value:

```
float64 = atan2(int64, int64)
```

One possible solution is to convert your `atan2` input arguments to match the type that numba seems to want to return from that function, which is evidently `float64`:

```
from numba import cuda, float64
import numpy
import math


@cuda.jit
def find_angle(angles):
    i, j = cuda.grid(2)
    if i < angles.shape[0] and j < angles.shape[1]:
        angles[i][j] = math.atan2(float64(j), float64(i))

block_x = 32
block_y = 32
block = (block_x, block_y)
x = 256
y = 256
grid = (x//block_x, y//block_y) # not for arbitrary x and y

angles = numpy.ones((x, y), numpy.float64)
find_angle[grid, block](angles)
```